# Meaning of the dialogue

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> "There was a light house which is a very special place and that morning I wanted to see it **for my self**"

This was a line I heard in a  TV show "How I Met Your Mother" and I was wondering what does this line mean especially this part "for my self".

Comment: I guess light house is written as one word ;lighthouse meaning a tall building near the coast or shore with a flashing light at the top to warn ships of rocks and other dangers. It can also mean a tower, building, or other type of structure designed to emit light from a system of lamps and lenses and used as a navigational aid for maritime pilots at sea or on inland waterways.

Comment: It should really be written as one word, "for **myself**".

Answer (score 3):

To

> see *something* for myself

literally means you want to go and have a look at *something* instead of only seeing a photo or watching it on TV.  By going and seeing it, one can get a feeling for the surroundings, atmosphere, and expanse of the location, and is also not limited by the narrow view of a photo or TV screen.

Other similar phrases are

> see it in the flesh
>   see it live
>   go have a look *( for myself )*